# Html/Js Audio without System Audio Controls

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to program a little browser game which needs some audio.

```
<audio id='my-audio' src='...'></audio>
```

That works on desktop and mobile but I have one problem: I can control this audio with the system audio controls. So when I press pause/play on my computer keyboard it affects this audio and on my phone's lock screen there appears a huge audio control widget. Is it possible to disable/remove these controls?

I also tried using

```
new Audio('...')
```

in Javascript instead of the audio-tag. That did not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: I worked on the project again and found the great library Howler.js. It is very easy to use and solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API). The link is to an example that I think covers a use case similar to what you requested. In addition to running the tutorial, I've also successfully used this API to read raw audio data (PCM array of float values) and play back on demand, which is a bit more involved than what you are asking. In either case, there was no issue with popups of any sort.